# Component in react doesnt execute in foreach loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const Course = props => {
  props.courses.forEach(course =>
  <Header name={course.name}/>
  )
  ...
}
```

This code doesnt execute Header at all. If I change the loop to `course => console.log(course.name)` instead, it works as intended and the data is correct. Whats the deal?

Answer (score 3):

[`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) does not return anything, and so you'll iterate through each of the courses absolutely fine, but you're not providing anything to render as a result of doing this.

Switching your `forEach` to something like [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), which returns an array of elements based on whatever you return from your function will provide - in this case - an array of elements to render.

You're also missing a return from your `Course` component, so make sure to add that in too.

For example:

```
const Course = props => {
  return props.courses.map(course =>
    <Header name={course.name}/>
  );
}
```

There are a few other things to bear in mind when working with arrays of components in React, so take a look at [Lists and Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) in the React docs if you want more info.

Answer (score 0):

you should use map instead of forEach

Comment: Doesnt work either way